chrome extension to add a new search engine with keyword
I built a custom search engine and I want to distribute it via chrome extension. The only thing I want this extension to do is to add a new search engine with a keyword shortcut.  I don't need anything else only adding a new search engine.
Is there any way to do so with a chrome extension?
